# Custom tooltip in flutter web

Tags: flutter, user-interface, flutter-web

[image]

I wanted to achieve this functionality in flutter web. Hover on any number element, this box appears with details. Till now I have created the widget with overlay and have achieved half of the result but the only issue I am facing is the position of the overlay. I want calculate the correct position where I can show this overlay accordingly like the tooltip. For instance, if I am at the end of the page and hover on the element the overlay cut it into half due to available space. Is there any work around for this or any flutter package available?

[image]

```
class _CustomToolTipState extends State<CustomToolTip> {
  OverlayState? overlayState;
  late OverlayEntry overlayEntry;
  double x = 0.0;
  double y = 0.0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    overlayState = Overlay.of(context);
    overlayEntry = OverlayEntry(
        builder: (context) => Positioned(
              top: y,
              left: x / 1.4,
              child: getCard(context),
            ));
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MouseRegion(
      onEnter: onEntered,
      onExit: onExit,
      onHover: _updateLocation,
      child: widget.child,
    );
  }

  void _updateLocation(PointerEvent details) {
    setState(() {
      x = details.position.dx;
      y = details.position.dy;
      //print('x & y $x $y');
    });
  }

  void onEntered(PointerEnterEvent event) => setState(() {
        //print('ENTERING .............');
        overlayState?.insert(overlayEntry);
      });

  void onExit(PointerEvent details) => setState(() {
        //print('LEAVING .............');
        overlayEntry.remove();
      });
}

Widget getCard(BuildContext context) {
  return SizedBox(
    child: Container(
      child: Padding(
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              getTextField('Carl Friedrich Usbeck KG [715]'),
              getDivider(),
              getTextField('Laborbrenner [29]'),
              getDivider(),
              getTextField('Nein'),
            ],
          )),
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: Don't know about any package but you could try to copy the code of the platform's regular `ToolTip` and modify the code as needed. I did it myself for the project I'm working on. Unfortunately I can't share it with you because it's not open source.

Comment: @Ivo I think this will help me a lot! Thank you so much for the direction.